# Multiple bundles with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

Let's say I have a library like this:

```
src
--- component1
-------- component1.scss
-------- component1.js   

--- component2
-------- component2.scss
-------- component2.js
```

and I want to distribute each component as an independent bundle, not as a common bundle for the whole app (component1 + component2 + etc):

```
dist
--- component1
-------- bundle1.js  

--- component2
-------- bundle.js
```

Is this achievable with just only one webpack config file or do I need to define an entry/ouput for each component?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use several entry points to achive this and split your code to chunks

```
{
  entry: { a: "./a", b: "./b" },
  output: { filename: "[name].js" },
  plugins: [ new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin("init.js") ]
}
```

https://webpack.js.org/concepts/output/#multiple-entry-points

Comment: Documentation link is broken.

Comment: whenever we need to add a .js file to the `src` directory, we need to make a change to the file `webpack.config.js`, which I don't like. Is there another way to doit?